# jquery simple alertbox based on some elements in A tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have one HTML page with 50 A tags and I want to create alert based on an element that i want to set inside the A. something like this:

```
<a href "something">click to see the alert</a>
```

i do not have any ideas about what should be places on the A tag. but i want to know how is it possible to to such thing with jquery.

I appreciate your help

Thank you so much

Comment: Just as a heads up there should be an equals sign between `href` and `something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the alert as a data-attribute, then just alert the data-value on click.

HTML

```
<a href="something" data-alert="Click to see the alert."></a>
```

JS

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('alert'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the click of a tag:

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text()+' - '+$(this).attr('href'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try;

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/hPN4u/3/)*** is a Live Demo